# is there a scaffolding tool for asp mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is there a tool that I can use to automaticaly create CRUD + ui for a model in asp mvc 4?

Answer (score 1):

There's **[ASP.NET MVC Scaffolding](http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/)**.

[Here's a series of blog posts](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) about the package by Steven Sanderson

Comment: Thanks. It does mentions that it is for mvc 3

Answer (score 0):

You could try an online tool like [CamoteQ Architecture](http://camoteq.com)